# Is it better to make a separate constructor and init method, or to create a constructors with parameters?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

As the question states, is it better to create a constructor and initializer like this (pseudocode):

```
public Component()  
{
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void initialize()  
{  
    this.value = parse(this.xml);
    arrayList.add(value);
}
```

In my case the initialization would have to read from an xml document and parse the values. The class would alse have a lot of other members that would be initialized using separate,more complex,methods. What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One clearcut advantage of doing the initialization work inside constructors is that the user of your class doesn't need to explicitly invoke init methods, and it avoids issues related objects not fully initialized. And in case you need to extend your class with some other class your initialization related code will get invoked appropriately.

I think what you can do is, have one init method that deals with all the initialization related code in private/protected scope and then call this method from the different constructors depending on different scenerios.

Comment: This is what made me think about what the better practice is. Somehow it seems to me, and this is subjective, that it is more readable when in main I call: `Component c = new Component(); c.init(); c.run(); `. But again, this is subjective and I think I will be going this way, using the init method inside the constructor.

Comment: I think from the readability perspective, 'new Component()' and 'c.init()' are same. Also note that typically we have init methods (in public scope) as callback methods (e.g. in case of servlet APIs).

Answer (score 5):

There is the builder pattern for complicated initialization.

```
X x = X.create()
    .setA(4)
    .setB("b")
    .end();

class X {
    private X() { }

    public static XBuilder create() {
    }

    public static class XBuilder {
        private X x;

        X end() {
            return x;
        }

        XBuilder setA(int a) {
            x.setA(a);
            return this;
        }
        XBuilder setB(String b) {
            x.setB(b);
            return this;
        }
    }
```

It uses a fluent interface, chained calls, and can be used to check for a complete initialization, doing work in `end()`.

Comment: `end()`? I would call it `build()`. Usually, I add the required parameters (to make the class work) inside the private constructor, and then all the auxiliary parameters are applied using set methods. I love this pattern when I can make it work. Never have that many parameters usually, but it does crop up from time to time.

Comment: Never used this kind of pattern. Thank you for your suggestion @Joop

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there's no single answer to this question. Coding standards are numerous and varied. For example, there will be standards giving guidelines such as

- Methods not too long.
- Methods not too complex.
- Overloaded methods to be grouped together.

In other words: if you think your constructor is getting too long and hard-to-read, then feel free to split up its functionality into multiple methods.

One advantage an init() method has over a constructor is that it can return a value, which may be useful for your application's purposes. On the other hand, you could throw exceptions inside the constructor to achieve something similar, this exception then being caught (and suitably processed) by the method that invokes the constructor.

Try searching the internet for coding standards, and you'll find numerous interesting discussions on this topic.

Comment: So following this idea - constructor + init method isn't considered a bad example? That's what I wanted to hear. The separation makes sense to me because of the code readability.

Comment: If you use a separate `init()` method, then you implicitly expect someone else to call this method. This can lead to problems that will go unnoticed until runtime. For example, your class attributes cannot be final anymore, and you have to add code to all your methods in order to check if they have been initialized.

Comment: @dotvav Although not using init() can cause problems too (not saying it's better). For example, suppose that a class named `Foo` has two private variables `bar` and `baz`. Suppose that when it initializes `bar`, it passes itself as a parameter to `bar`'s constructor. Suppose then that during its (constructor) initialization, the `bar` object calls `methodX()` on our `Foo` class. If `methodX()` expects `baz` to be defined, but the initialization of `baz` occurs later in the constructor, you will get a runtime error. If `Bar` had an explicit `init()` called in `Foo.init()`, no error would occur.